# THS7001 PGA input voltage drop issue

Tags: ltspice, simulation, voltage-divider, programmable-gain-amplifier

I am having issues simulating the [THS7001](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ths7001) programmable gain amplifier (PGA). I have the following setup:

[image]

I added a voltage divider at the input R11/(R10+R11) = 0.5, and configured the pre-amp stage of the THS7001 as a voltage follower.

When I apply a 10 kHz, 1 V signal at the input of the voltage divider, I measure a voltage of ~360 mV at Vin.

[image: Voltage at Vin with R11 = R10 = 100kΩ]

Oddly enough, when I reduce the resistances R10 and R11 to 1 kΩ the problem seems to go away, and I measure the expected ~500 mV at Vin:

[image: Voltage at Vin with R11 = R10 = 1kΩ]

The same happens when I increase R10 and R11 to high resistances (1 MΩ):

[image: Voltage at Vin with R11 = R10 = 1MΩ]

It seems that the issue is only with the pre-amp stage of the THS7001.

I imported the PSpice model of the THS7001 (Rev B) from Texas Instruments to my LTspice simulation using instructions found [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-import-spice-model-ltspice-petr-dvo%C5%99%C3%A1k/).

Any advice on why I am getting this weird behavior will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're using 1 megaohm?  `1M` means 1 milli in SPICE.  You need to type in `1meg` to get 1 mega.

Comment: I have indeed used 1M in the simulation. Changing to 1meg now causes a much larger voltage error, which makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the datasheet:
[image]

The output impedance from your divider is 50K, so these currents cause a significant voltage error.  When you drop to 1K resistors, the the output impedance is 500 ohms, so the currents cause relatively little problem.  As @Ste Kulov points out, 1 milliohm resistors make the problem almost completely disappeaar.

These amplifiers are designed for high frequency, relatively low impedance signals.

Comment: Thanks. This makes a lot of sense. When calculating the voltage drop based on the bias current in the data sheet, it corresponds to the signal I am measuring in the simulation. I guess I will drop the value of the voltage divider resistors for now.